# Can my machine read messages from another local machine if my MessageQueue is private?

Tags: c#, msmq

I want to receive messages from another computer on the local network so I created `MessageQueue` in this way:

```
private static string QueueName = ".\\Private$\\Q1";
    public void SendMessage()
    {           
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(QueueName))
            MessageQueue.Create(QueueName);

        //
    }

    public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        // Connect to the a queue on the local computer.
        MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(QueueName);

        // Set the formatter to indicate body contains an Order.
        myQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(Queue.Order) });

        try
        {
            // Receive and format the message. 
            Message myMessage = myQueue.Receive();
            ///
    }
```

I also tried to create my `MessageQueue` with the format of `@"MachineName\QueueName"` but received a MessageQueueException.

Comment: I believe that Private$ just controls whether the queue is published (in active directory). The permissions on the queue are set separately.

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "Computer Management" and look under "Services and Applications" > "Message Queueing" > "Private Queues" do you see your queue named "Q1"?  If so, are there any messages in it?  You may need to adjust the properties on the queue (right click > Properties > Security).  If you're in a development environment you can start by giving Everyone Full Control.  Once you have it working, try to figure out the minimum set of permissions.  You may also want to create the queue from the computer management mmc, rather than in the code.

Comment: My crash occurs in MessageQueue.Create, private Queue works fine

Comment: @user1860934 - Can you create it from the Computer Management mmc?  If your Windows user does not have permission, then any code you run will not either.

Comment: Right click on private queues --> new will create private